# Is there an Apache variable that contains JUST the filename - with no path

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

I have a lot of these redirects:

```
RewriteRule ^demos/(bar-3d-effect-multi-row\.html)        demos-website/$1
RewriteRule ^demos/(bar-adjustable\.html)                 demos-website/$1
RewriteRule ^demos/(bar-ajax\.html)                       demos-website/$1
RewriteRule ^demos/(bar-basic\.html)                      demos-website/$1
RewriteRule ^demos/(bar-dark-background\.html)            demos-website/$1
RewriteRule ^demos/(bar-google-power-usage\.html)         demos-website/$1
RewriteRule ^demos/(bar-i-love-my-dog-de-bordeaux\.html)  demos-website/$1
RewriteRule ^demos.(bar-images-as-labels\.html)           demos-website/$1
RewriteRule ^demos/(bar-interactive-key\.html)            demos-website/$1
RewriteRule ^demos/(bar-line-switch-effect\.html)         demos-website/$1

...
```

Is there a way to condense all of these redirects into a few lines? Perhaps like this:

```
RewriteCond ^demos-website/%{FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^demos/%{FILENAME}   /demos-website/%{FILENAME}
```

So that it only rewrites the URL if the file exists in the demos-website directory?

Comment: You can refer: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html#vars

Answer (score 1):

Please be aware that there may be issues with the regex as I couldn't test it very well myself, use it at your own risk:

```
# sets filename to the file name
RewriteRule ^demos\/.*?([^\/]+)\/*$ - [ENV=filename:$1]
# checks if the file exists in the other directory
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/demos-website/%{ENV:filename} -f
# redirect if it is true
RewriteRule ^demos/ /demos-website/%{ENV:filename} [R,L]
```

And you can refer to https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html#vars for variables that can be used with mod_rewrite.

Comment: Didn't work. The first line did where it sets the environment variable - but I think that my hosting providers (Ionos)  Apache installation is non-standard. For example, after setting the environment variable on the first line if I then dump all of the environment variables to screen with PHP it comes through as REDIRECT_filename - ie it has REDIRECT_ prepended to the name. But no matter - I just thought (it happens...) of a way to do it - I redirect all of the demo files to the demos-website. If the requested page doesn't exist it just 404's. Since there won't be any links to them - no biggie

Comment: So I ended up using this: RewriteRule ^demos/(.*\.html) /demos-website/$1

Comment: Not precisely, if I comment out the middle line it works - but not with.

Comment: @Richard, well then, it could be that your installation of Apache in your server is very different from the usual as you said, or we are missing something important here. Anyways, if that's the case, maybe you can replace the filename in the other 2 lines to REDIRECT_filename